# Print in Command Window without 'ans = ' in matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf, command-window

When I use sprintf, the results show like this :

```
sprintf('number=%d %d %d',a,b,c)
sprintf('or %d',h)  

ans = 

number= 5 4 2

ans =

or 2
```

How can I display the results without `ans =` obstructing them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fprintf` instead of `sprintf`. Remember to put a newline `\n` at the end of your strings.

Comment: Oh ... that was simple, thank you (need to wait before accepting).

Answer (score 6):

## Summary

**Option 1**: `disp(['A string: ' s ' and a number: ' num2str(x)])`

**Option 2**: `disp(sprintf('A string: %s and a number %d', s, x))`

**Option 3**: `fprintf('A string: %s and a number %d\n', s, x)`

## Details

Quoting http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html (Display Multiple Variables on Same Line)

There are three ways to display multiple variables on the same line in the Command Window.

**(1)** Concatenate multiple strings together using the [] operator. Convert any numeric values to characters using the num2str function. Then, use disp to display the string.

```
name = 'Alice';   
age = 12;
X = [name,' will be ',num2str(age),' this year.'];
disp(X)
```

`Alice will be 12 this year.`

**(2)** You also can use sprintf to create a string. Terminate the sprintf command with a semicolon to prevent "X = " from being displayed. Then, use disp to display the string.

```
name = 'Alice';   
age = 12;
X = sprintf('%s will be %d this year.',name,age);
disp(X)
```

`Alice will be 12 this year.`

**(3)** Alternatively, use fprintf to create and display the string. Unlike the sprintf function, fprintf does not display the "X = " text. However, you need to end the string with the newline (\n) metacharacter to terminate its display properly.

```
name = 'Alice';   
age = 12;
X = fprintf('%s will be %d this year.\n',name,age);
```

`Alice will be 12 this year.`